# How to make 'siunitx' use \textpm

Tags: siunitx

[siunitx 2018/05/17, xelatex (TeXLive 2018)]

What must I do to make `siunitx` use the `\textpm` symbol?  Looking into the code I see that `siunitx` checks whether package `textcomp` is loaded, apparently replacing all occurrences of `\pm` with `\textpm` in the output.  However, I don't see any change in behaviour whatever combination or option I try...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\textpm
\num[separate-uncertainty=true,
     mode=text]{1 +- 2}
\end{document}
```

[image: \textpm vs. \pm]

Comment: Note that the problem disappears if I use the `libertinus-otf` package.  However, this just hides the issue since this package provides a libertine-style math font.

Comment: There are a few places that are 'implicitly math mode' in the current release: this is one of them.: it's fixed in the development code for v3